# Change membership expiration rules

Tags: civimember

We want membership signups or renewals to expire at the end of the following year if made after July 1. So for example you sign up today (Sept 2018), then your membership is good through Dec 31, 2019.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by:

- Going to **Administer menu >> CiviMember >> Membership Types**.
- Next to each membership type you'd like this to apply to, click the "Edit" link (see screenshot 1 below).
- On the Membership Type screen, set **Membership Type Plan** to "Fixed", set **Fixed Period Start Day** to "January 1st", and **Fixed Period Rollover Day** to "July 1st" (see screenshot 2 below).
- Press **Save**.

[image]
[image]